# Xamarin RestSharp: Json object send to Azure Web API with result null response

Tags: android, json, xamarin, restsharp

I am using RestSharp on Xamarin to communicate with WebAPI using POST. I can send something and get a response but the outcome wasn't what I expected.

This is my code on Xamarin.

```
                var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest ("api/device/stats", RestSharp.Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(new AppUsageInfo {MAC = "ASDF"}); 
            RestSharp.IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
            var content = response.Content;
```

On my WebAPI :

```
 public string Post([FromUri]UsageLogModel usageState)
    {
        //LogFunction.AddUsageLogs(usageState);
        if (usageState.MAC == null)
            return "fail";
        else
            return "success";
    }
```

UsageLogModel is :

```
public class UsageLogModel
{
    public string MAC;
}
```

Somehow the response is "Fail" which MAC is null. I scratched my head but have no idea what is going on.-

Comment: The type used in rest request `AppUsageInfo`is different from the one you're expecting in you post method `UsageLogModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xamarin code is putting the MAC content in the body of the request (which is probably appropriate for a POST), but the Web API is expected the parameter to be in the query string (that's what the [FromUri] attribute is doing).  Try changing the Web API method to:

```
public string Post([FromBody]UsageLogModel usageState)
```